# Questão de atividade: Como fazer digito verificador do CEP em PHP

Tags: php, cep

Uma questão de prova de lógica

É feito a partir da soma dos 8 dígitos do CEP, então subtrai-se o resultado da soma dos algarismos do CEP do múltiplo de 10 imediatamente superior ao resultado.

Por exemplo: CEP: 71010050 à 7 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 5 + 0 = 14
Subtrai-se 14 de 20.
Validador = 6

Já fiz essa parte:

```
        $cepCliente = "41600-610";
        $cepClienteSemTraco = str_replace("-", "", $cepCliente);
        $cepClienteArray = str_split($cepClienteSemTraco);
        $cepClienteNumero01 = (int) $cepClienteArray[0];
        $cepClienteNumero02 = (int) $cepClienteArray[1];
        $cepClienteNumero03 = (int) $cepClienteArray[2];
        $cepClienteNumero04 = (int) $cepClienteArray[3];
        $cepClienteNumero05 = (int) $cepClienteArray[4];
        $cepClienteNumero06 = (int) $cepClienteArray[5];
        $cepClienteNumero07 = (int) $cepClienteArray[6];
        $cepClienteNumero08 = (int) $cepClienteArray[7];
        $cepClienteNumero09 = (int) $cepClienteArray[8];
        $somaCep = $cepClienteNumero01+$cepClienteNumero02+$cepClienteNumero03+$cepClienteNumero04+$cepClienteNumero05+$cepClienteNumero06+$cepClienteNumero07+$cepClienteNumero08+$cepClienteNumero09;
```

O resto não estou conseguindo fazer

Comment: Cep não tem validação, isso é impreciso...a única coisa que vc pode verificar é se ele tem 8 dígitos.

Comment: @IvanFerrer É uma questão de prova

Comment: você pode também pegar do webservice do correio, ou da url, e tratar a entrada dessa página: `https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se esse tipo de validação de CEP é preciso, mas levando em conta a sua necessidade de encontrar esse validados, pode-se fazer algo do tipo.

```
    $cepCliente = "41600-610";
    $cepClienteSemTraco = str_replace("-", "", $cepCliente);
    $cepClienteArray = str_split($cepClienteSemTraco);
    $somaCep = 0;
    foreach ($cepClienteArray as $pos){
        $somaCep += $pos;
    }
```

Segundo sua fórmula, agora é preciso subtrair do múltiplo de 10 imediatamente superior ao resultado:

```
$multiplo = ceil($somaCep/ 10) * 10;
$validador = $multiplo - $somaCep;
```

O **ceil** irá arredondar para cima o resultado da divisão, então multilpicamos esse resultado por 10 para obter o próximo multiplo de 10.

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado!

Comment: Você não acha que é melhor usar um `for` para percorrer todos os dígitos e calcular a soma, em vez de uma linha de programa e uma nova variável para cada dígito?

Comment: @jsbueno Eu só tinha pegado o código do op e complementado o restante que ele pediu, considerei seu comentário e alterei a soma pra uma maneira mais enxuta

Comment: Não seria mais simples utilizar o operador de resto da divisão: $validador = 10 - ($somaCep % 10); ?